# App keeps crashing when i try to login in an app i made

Tags: java, android, button, methods, crash

basic app to take username and password and register (registration works) but when i press the button for login, it crashes. Code for signin:

```
signin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent1);
    }
}
```

expected to see login scree, but keeps quitting to phone home screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### have you declared LoginActivity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
If not, do it like this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".LoginActivity">
</activity>
```

---

Comment: It works now! i changed the class name after creating it hence the crash! I am new to android studio so i didnt even know this. You're a LIFESAVER!